# Integrating this physics expression

Tags: calculus, physics

Recall: $dp= \rho g \ dh$ where $dp$ is the change in pressure, $ \rho$ is the constant of density and $dh$ is the change in height. This is a part of fluid dynamics (buoyancy).

I am to integrate this expression to show that if $ \rho$ is constant then the pressure at depth $h$ is given by: $p = p_o + \rho g h$.

But I'm not really getting there with the integral methods that I know !

Comment: $\large dp=(\rho g) dh\Rightarrow \frac{dp}{dh}=\rho g$. Can you take this further?

Comment: Yes, will I integrate twice, once with respect to p and once with respect to h...?

Comment: The right hand side is a constant, and you need to integrate  *once* with respect to $h$.

Comment: I get $p = \rho g h$ then which is good. Am I supposed to get $p_o$ or just add it and explain that I need to add atmospheric pressure or?

Comment: The $p_0$ is a constant - when you integrate a function, the result is another function (the integral) plus a constant $C$- that is how the mathematics works out. In your case, the constant is $p_0$- this has a basis in the physical system, as it corresponds to the atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Do I not need to prove that this constant is indeed P0?

Comment: I'm not sure - you can state that it is a constant $C$, and find its value by setting the depth $h$ to $0$, so that $C=p_0$, the pressure at depth 0, which is the atmospheric pressure.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It comes down to this:
$$
\int_0^{h} dp = p(h) - p_0\\
\int_0^{h} dp=\int_0^{h}\rho g\,dh = \rho g\int_0^{h}\,dh = ?
$$
Use this to solve for $p(h)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but this just confuses me further.

You are integrating from 0 to h0?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that should just be "$h$"; I mixed up notation. Generally, you're not supposed to be integrating with respect to the variable that you have in the limits of the integral.